# iOS - NSUserDefaults not saving when my viewWillDisappear is called

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save my NSUserDefaults when the `viewWillDisappear` is called on one of my subviews. I can confirm it is getting called.

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:@"test" forKey:@"123"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

However whenever I restart the app and try to use it:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults objectForKey@"test"])
    NSLog(@"did not exist");
else 
    NSLog(@"found it");
```

it never finds it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are swapping your key and object. It should be:

```
if (![defaults objectForKey@"123"])
```